# Airflow ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I installed Airflow on my machine which works well and I have a local spark also (which is operational too).
I want to use airflow to orchestrate two sparks tasks: `task_spark_datatransform >> task_spark_model_reco`.
The two pyspark modules associated to these two tasks are tested and work well under spark.

I also create a very simple Airflow Dag using `bashOperator`* to run each spark task. For example, for the task `task_spark_datatransform` I have:

```
task_spark_datatransform = BashOperator (task_id = 'task_spark_datatransform', bash_command = spark_home + 'spark-submit --master local [*]' + srcDir + 'dataprep.py'),
where, in my case, spark_home = '/usr/bin/spark/bin/'
```

*As indicated in several serious tutorials on this same subject.

Question: Why doesn't Airflow recognize pyspark?

Log:

```
[2019-09-20 10:21:21 +0200] [5945] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5945)
[2019-09-20 10:21:51 +0200] [5554] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-09-20 10:21:51 +0200] [6128] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6128
[2019-09-20 10:21:51,609] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-09-20 10:21:52,021] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ach/airflow/dags
[2019-09-20 10:21:52,026] {__init__.py:416} ERROR - Failed to import: /home/ach/airflow/dags/spark_af.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ach/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 413, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/home/ach/airflow/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ach/airflow/dags/spark_af.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dataprep
  File "/home/ach/airflow/dags/dataprep.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

Comment: Are you sure that your Airflow and PySpark environment are consistent? I see that Airflow is using `Python 3.7`, are you sure that when you launch `pyspark` shell on your machine, that also employs the same `Python 3.7`?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. AirFlow and Spark installed on the same node. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing `pyspark`:

Run the following:

```
pip install pyspark
```

Comment: Thanks @kaxil ... But, why do I have to install the pyspark package (pip install pyspark) while airflow and spark are installed on the same machine and I can run pyspark from any directory (SPARK_HOME is added to my .profile file) ?

Comment: Are you running Airflow & PySpark in the same environment? Or are you running Airflow in a virtual environment?

Comment: Indeed, Airflow is running from its own virtual environment (on my local machine).
Spark is installed on my local machine in a traditional way (without virtual environment).
By the way, ($ pyspark) launches correctly from the environment environment airflow. 
What did I miss?